# react: helping to understand specific currying use case

Tags: reactjs, currying

```
  <Select 
    onChange={evt => myFunction('KEY', ['ARRAY', 'OF', 'VALUES'])(evt)}
```

...

```
 const myFunction = (key, funValues) => {

      return (evt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {

        const { values } = evt.target;
         if (funValues.find( some condition) ){
           callAPI(key, funValues);
         }
         else{
           callAPI(key, values);
        }
      };
    };
```

I would have written this simply as

```
 onChange={evt => myFunction('KEY', ['ARRAY', 'OF', 'VALUES'], evt)}
```

I am really failing to see what was the logic of applying currying here, and how it will make 
a) this operation better 
and/or 
b) contributes to broader benefits

Maybe this helps with context, but `myFunction` is called throughout the codebase. Sometimes via an evt, and sometimes manually.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? What's the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a curried function (I guess) is a misunderstanding for avoiding an arrow function in the callback handler. In order to this misunderstanding some people define this function as a curried one and use such as:

```
onChange={myFunction('KEY', ['ARRAY', 'OF', 'VALUES'])}
```

As you can see this is somehow shorter than your version and works. So, you don't have to use an arrow function and invoke it as you do. `event` is passed again.

Some people think that this avoids a recreation of this function in each render, but that is not true.

Comment: this is what appears to be happening in this case. thank you for the insight